# PHP Regexp negative lookahead

Tags: php, regex-negation

I'm trying match all words wrapped with  { } but not the words with "_loop".  I can't see where I'm going wrong with my reg expression.

```
 $content   = '<h1>{prim_practice_name}</h1><p>{prim_content}</p><p>Our Locations Are {location_loop}{name} - {state}<br/>{/location_loop}</p>';
 $pattern = '/\{(\w*(?!\_loop))\}/';
```

Comment: You are looking for a lookbehind `?<!`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because \w* "eats" the stopping word "_loop" before your check, to prevent that you should check the word first (before \w*), like the following:

```
$pattern = '/\{((?!\w*_loop\})\w*)\}/';
```

or you can use: `?< !` :

```
$pattern = '/\{(\w*(?<!_loop))\}/';
```