# PHP Match the string to regex, if after the matched string are no digits

Tags: php, regex

Lets say that I have a excel function like that `IF(A1>0,1,2)` I match it by pregex and by dictionary I translate it into Czech language (`KDYŽ(A1>0,1,2)`). When I would translate it back I should get the same string, but instead of it I get `IF(AND1>0,1,2)`. Because "A" is in Czech "AND" which is one of key words in excel function.

So I need to grep all letters while after them is no number (= not cell name), how to achieve that while I'm using this code to get array of matched words?

```
$text = strtolower("KDYŽ(A1>0,1,2)");

if (preg_match_all('/[a-zěščřžýáíéúůóďťň]+/i',$text,$match)) {
  /* matched text should be:
  $match[0] = "KDYŽ";
  no $match[1] = "A" should exists;*/
}
```

Comment: Function is: strtolower(), (notice 'w'!) just change it. :)

Comment: thanks, it was just in case to show how the code works

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Regexp negative lookahead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626955/php-regexp-negative-lookahead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
'/[a-zěščřžýáíéúůóďťň]+[^0-9]/i'
```

which maches your characters not followed by a 0-9. You'd need to strip the last character from your match though since the first character following the string you search will be returned, too.

Or, try

```
'/[a-zěščřžýáíéúůóďťň]+(?![0-9])/i'
```

which is a negative look-ahead.

Comment: Or one more question how to achieve the same if there is [0-9] or the end of string?

Comment: Using the lookahead you could try `'/[a-zěščřžýáíéúůóďťň]+(?!([0-9]|$))/i'`